# List pages (with links) from website by Python

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get a list of website pages links. But I have a problem with the URL. The code underneath only gives me links to the first page.

```
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

page = 1
while page != 6:
      url = f"https://www.autocentrum.pl/stacje-paliw/?strona-{page}/?s=5&order=&q="
      print(url)
      page = page + 1
```

Any ideas how to change the url to fix it?

Comment: You'r code works fine for me, can you be more precise on the issue.

Comment: Note that if you click, for example, on link 3, the content is still displayed as of the first page (there are over 400 pages of all pages - autocentrum.pl/stacje-paliw/?s=5&order=&q=). Finally, I would like to get, for example, 5 links to the first 5 pages of the website.

Comment: Down vote, cause your question should include more details and clarify the problem. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to improve and [edit].  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what the expected output should be, but for me it is this. Is it possible that you wanted to change the `s=5` parameter of the request?

```
https://www.autocentrum.pl/stacje-paliw/?strona-1/?s=5&order=&q=
https://www.autocentrum.pl/stacje-paliw/?strona-2/?s=5&order=&q=
https://www.autocentrum.pl/stacje-paliw/?strona-3/?s=5&order=&q=
https://www.autocentrum.pl/stacje-paliw/?strona-4/?s=5&order=&q=
https://www.autocentrum.pl/stacje-paliw/?strona-5/?s=5&order=&q=
```

I would also recommend using a for loop instead.

```py
for page in range(1,6):
    url = f"https://www.autocentrum.pl/stacje-paliw/?strona-{page}/?s=5&order=&q="
    print(url)
```

Comment: The "s" is equivalent to the normal "page" but the same is for "strona".
Note that if you click, for example, on link 3, the content is still displayed as of the first page (there are over 400 pages of all pages - https://www.autocentrum.pl/stacje-paliw/?s=5&order=&q=). Finally, I would like to get, for example, 5 links to the first 5 pages of the website.

Comment: Could you please include the links that you want? We don't know how that website works and which pages you exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

page = 1
while page != 6:
    url = f"https://www.autocentrum.pl/stacje-paliw/strona-{page}/?s={page}&order=&q="
    print(url)
    page = page + 1
```